# what does -:} && mean in bash script

Tags: bash, syntax

We are calling bash script from Jenkinsfile which evaluates boolean parameter for running authentication script:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
some case statements 
esac
$APP_PARAM:-} && key_aliase="xyz/aaa"
some parameter set
call another shellscript
```

and wondering what `$APP_PARAM:-} && key_aliase="xyz/aaa"` means. APP_PARAM is boolean parameter with default value false.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a typo for

```
${APP_PARAM:-} && keyaliase="xyzzy/aaa"
```

The result is that either `$APP_PARAM` expands to a program to run, and `key_aliase` is set only if the program succeeds, or the parameter expands to an empty string which, since it is unquoted, becomes a "null" command that is considered to succeed unconditionally.

Given that `${APP_PARAM}` and `${APP_PARAM:-}` produce the same result when expanded, I assume that the script uses `set -u` to exit on any attempt to expand an undefined parameter. The latter form expands to an empty string instead of triggering the exit.